# What's the proper way to fix a broken COM registration?

Tags: com, activex, dll

We have an .ocx file containing 2 ActiveX controls. One thing led to another and... now we're in "dll hell." One control loads fine within the containing application, and the other control (the one that was modified) fails to load completely. Without a doubt its because we [broke compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyv3a.png) by changing several event and method signatures. (**That** ought to teach us to unregister old .ocx's before registering new ones...)

In the past I recall having to go into the registry and manually remove important looking entries from `HKCR\TypeLib`, but that's scary stuff. What is the generally accepted solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried a registry cleaner (a tool like CCLEANER)? Sometimes, these tools are able to fix these activex issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your COM registration is genuinely broken, the only way I know of to fix it is to do a search through the registry for the CLSIDs in question and delete *all* references to it.

Yeah, it's a little dangerous; that's why an activex control is supposed to *safely* register itself, and why MS now recommends using an MSI for installs and not doing a selfreg (regsvr32) in the install process.  Once something gets messed up on a system, it can be a pain to fix it.

However, if you figure out the relevant CLSIDs (the CLSID for each control and the typelib) and remove only things that reference those you should be okay; to be safe, set a system restore point before you start.

Good luck